# Java - Retrieve values of variable type from JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I have some `JSON` like so:

```
{"result":[{"job":{"type":"Employee","title":"","occupation":"Underwater Basket Weaver"}}]}
```

I am getting the occupation value like so:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

String occupation = null;

JSONArray resultArray = obj.getJSONArray("result");
JSONObject firstResult = resultArray.getJSONObject(0);
occupation = firstResult.getJSONObject("job").getString("occupation");
```

However, for some reason, the occupation value is not always a `String`. My guess is that is could be an `int` or it could be `null`. I end up with an exception like this:

> org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["occupation"] not a string.
>       at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:658)

What should you do when you are dealing with JSONObjects that take on variable data types?

Comment: You might have to test if `getString("occupation")` is valid with `isNull(String)`. According to http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#getString(java.lang.String) , `getString(...)` throws the exception if it doesn't find one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Apply this to receive all the data types in string format**

```
occupation = firstResult.getJSONObject("job").get("occupation").toString();
```

Comment: This will have NullPointerException if `firstResult.getJSONObject("job").get("occupation")` returns null.

Comment: So, you do this boldface thing all the time, then?

Answer (score 1):

This is your initial Json:

```
{"result":[{"job":{"type":"Employee","title":"","occupation":"Underwater Basket Weaver"}}]}
```

when you do this:

```
JSONArray resultArray = obj.getJSONArray("result");
```

You get:

```
[{"job":{"type":"Employee","title":"","occupation":"Underwater Basket Weaver"}}]
```

Then:

JSONObject firstResult = resultArray.getJSONObject(0);

You get:

```
{"job":{"type":"Employee","title":"","occupation":"Underwater Basket Weaver"}}
```

Next:

```
firstResult.getJSONObject("job")
```

Produce:

```
{"type":"Employee","title":"","occupation":"Underwater Basket Weaver"}
```

To finish, is you wanna get the **occupation** value use: **get("occupation")**.

Comment: Your answer reminded me the video on "if google was a guy" when he was shouting "That is not what she asked for".

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
String occupation = String.valueOf(firstResult.getJSONObject("job").get("occupation"));
```

if the field `occupation` always has a value(not array or another JSON object).

Answer (score 0):

**I had your problem as well, when you mentioned:**

> However, for some reason, the occupation value is not always a String.
> My guess is that is could be an int or it could be null. I end up with
> an exception like this:

**Answer:**
When your JSON column data type isnt Integer,String... it needs to be defined as an Object or a Class

```
Object o = new Object();
```

and then you can use the if-else conditions to check what the wrapper class(your type) can be and then do the following accordingly.
Check the image below please.

[image]

source of image :
https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-check-object-type-java.cfm